# Numbers where there is a unique group with integral character table

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

Call a number $n$ special in case there is a unique group of order n whose character table consists of only integers. This should be equivalent to the condition that the number of conjugacy classes coincides with the number of conjugacy classes of cyclic subgroups.

> Questions: What is the sequence of special numbers? It starts with 1,2, 4, 6, 12, 18, 54,120. Is it an infinite sequence?
>
> For which $m$ is $m!$ special ?(note that the symmetric group has integral character table and thus $n!$ is a good candidate for being special)

[Side question: For which m are the groups of order m! classified?]

> What are the corresponding unique groups of order $n$ for $n$ being special?

The sequence of such groups starts with $\mathbb{Z}_1, \mathbb{Z}_2, \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2, S_3,D_{12}, (\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2,(\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2, S_5$

Comment: I don't get the definition.  What is $n$?  Is it the order of the group?

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill Yes. Thanks I forgot that and added it now.

Comment: I believe that Pal Hegedus proved that solvable groups with a rational character table are all $\{2,3,5\}$-groups, with an elementary Abelian normal Sylow $5$-subgroup. It is not clear to me at the moment which numbers $n$ of the form $n= 2^{a}3^{b}5^{c}$ have a chance of being special.